Is there always a cycle with only one Tutte bridge in a 3-regular graph?
Given a cubic connected graph $G$ and a cycle $C$ of $G$ a Tutte bridge of $(G,C)$ is a connected component of $G-E(C)$.
I was wondering if for every cubic graph there exists a cycle which only has one Tutte bridge.

I think you need $G$ to be connected.

Yes, I forgot to mention that I've added it to the question

I also believe your definition of bridge is wrong. I believe Tutte means a bridge sould either be an edge with both ends in $C$, or a component outside $C$ together with its attachments in $C$.

Let $C$ be a cycle of a $(G, C)$-Tutte bridge. If one of the non-maximum $(G ,C)$-Tutte bridges (in terms of the number of edges; we consider the maximum Tutte-bridge to be unique, if there are ties, we fix one and say the other are non-maximum) has a cycle, it is easy to show that all the other $(G, C)$-Tutte bridges will be connected in $G-E(C')$ (because $C$ and $C'$ can't intersect), thus the size of the maximum Tutte-bridge will augment.
Otherwise, all the non-maximum Tutte bridges are trees, with the leaves belonging to $C$. Let $A$ be a non-maximum Tutte-bridge and $u$ and $v$ be two leaves of $A$. Let $P$ be one of the two $u,v$-paths in $C$ and let $C'$ be the cycle formed by $P$ and by the unique $u,v$-path of $A$. If for all Tutte bridge $A'\neq A$, $P$ does not contain all the vertices of $A'\cap C$, then all these Tutte bridges will be connected in $G-E(C')$, leading to a bigger maximum Tutte bridge.
It can be shown that there are at least three Tutte bridges such that at least one of the $u,v$-paths does not completely overlap the vertices of another Tutte bridge (This can be shown by recursively taking the overlapped Tutte bridge). Of these three, at least one is not the maximum Tutte bridge. Taking the cycle as described above will augment the size of the maximum Tutte bridge.
We keep iterating until $G-E(c)$ is connected.
Note that there is not much that is inherent to cubic graphs, essentially the same proof will work for a connected graph with no pendant vertex.
